# Triangulating a simple polygon via its trapezoidal map

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

Given a trapezoidal map of a simple polygon $P$, is it possible to compute the triangulation of $P$ in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "it's easy to derive from such a decomposition of $P$ in linear time a triangulation of $P$."

Take a look at lemma 1. [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/A%20Simple%20and%20fast.pdf).